# text not displaying in uitabbar

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have code in didFinishLaunching method as per below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
myViewController *obj=[[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
myOtherViewController *obj2=[[myOtherViewController alloc]init];
NSArray *controller=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj,obj2, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers=controller;

tabBarController.tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"footprints" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"] tag:0];
tabBarController.tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:0];
self.window.rootViewController=tabBarController;

return YES;
}
```

but, When app runs it is not showing text  "footprints" or any image.